Smooth partition of unity for bounded open sets in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $C^1$ boundary.
Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary. Suppose $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is an open cover of $\overline{U},$ I wonder whether there exists a smooth partition of unity $\{\zeta_k\}$ subordinate to $\{U_k\},$ that is, $\{\zeta_k\}$ satisfies the following conditions:
$\bullet ~0\leq \zeta_k\leq 1$
$\bullet ~\sum_{k=1}^n\zeta_k = 1$
$\bullet ~\zeta_k\in C^\infty(\overline{U_k})$
(In fact, this result is used without proof to prove the Theorem 3 in subsection 5.3.3
in the book "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans)

Yes, such a partition of unity always exists. To be fair, a lot of books don't contain a proof of this fact and refer to other literature, but e.g. the book "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I" by Lars Hörmander (Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg, 1990, 2nd edition) does contain a proof in chapter 1.4
